# Error assigning value using TOP 1

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Here's my code that results in error :

```
SELECT @maxNo = TOP 1 CONVERT(INT,(SUBSTRING(noorder,7,4))) 
FROM orders ORDER BY noorder DESC;
```

It returns:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'TOP'.

EDIT :
found the answer, i should code like this :

```
select top 1 @maxNo = CONVERT(int, (SUBSTRING(noorder, 7, 4)))
```

from orders
order by noorder desc;

thanks to @RedFilter

Comment: accept means choose an answer most helpful to me, right? so it's done. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select top 1 @maxNo = CONVERT(int, (SUBSTRING(noorder, 7, 4)))
from orders
order by noorder desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 declare @maxNo int
 Set @maxNo = (Select TOP 1 CONVERT(INT,(SUBSTRING(noorder,7,4))) 
 FROM [order] order by  noorder desc)
 select @maxNo
```

Comment: Updated had to remove the semi colon ..!

Comment: Great, can you remove the horizontal scrollbar too? (I would but I got reprimanded last week for editing someone else's post.)